# connect-flash not displaying any message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm using connect-flash package but couldn't find a way to do it right.

for example in my login function I do something like below

```
req.flash('error','User not found!');
```

so how can I display it?

Answer (score 0):

you can extract contents of flash message like this and inject into template being rendered:

```
app.get('/auth/success', function(req,res){
  res.render('auth/success', {'flash':req.flash()});
});
```

Comment: I was trying this repo https://github.com/eldyvoon/register-login-nodejs/tree/master it's missing the error message. the author didn't do the res.render.